# How to write a 2D array into a file and back in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm trying to save a board (which is a 2D array that has been dynamically allocated) into a file such that it can be later "loaded" by the user and they can use the board again. To save the board the user must input `s filename`. To get the user input, I have an else if statement for the save command:

```
else if (playerMove.command == 's') {
    char* fileName = NULL;
    scanf(" %s", fileName);
    implementSave(boardState, fileName);
```

Since we've only learned how to read/open/write to binary files in C, I tried to do the same for this in my implementSave function:

```
void implementSave(BoardState* boardState, char* fileName) {
  FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "wb");
  fwrite(fileName, sizeof(char), sizeof(boardState->board.theBoard), file);
  fclose(file);
}
```

Note: I use some structs in my program; the struct `board` contains `char** theBoard, int numRows, int numCols, char blankSpace`.

However, this gives me an error when I try to run the save command. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of error? If it is just not saving correctly, that is because the `sizeof` a `char**` is 4 or 8 (or something like that). You should compute the number of character cells to save or load directly: `boardState->board.numRows*boardState->board.numCols`.

Comment: `char* fileName = NULL;  scanf(" %s", fileName);` -- you have allocated no storage for the `fileName`.... Also note that the `%s` directive _automatically_ skips over leading whitespace, so no need for the leading space in the format string.

Comment: Depends on what is `BoardState`. But `fwrite(fileName, sizeof(char), sizeof(boardState->board.theBoard), file);` looks totally wrong anyway. Did you mean `fwrite(boardState, sizeof(char), sizeof(boardState->board.theBoard), file);`?

Comment: you won't be able to write out `theBoard` if it's a `char **` as each element of `theBoard` is a pointer and it'd be meaningless - you'd need to write out each row separately

Comment: @Dúthomhas whenever I enter "s filename" it outputs "Process finished with exit code 11". Would `boardState->board.numRows*boardState->board.numCols` be the 3rd parameter for fwrite?

Comment: @DavidBowling how would I allocate enough space for `fileName` then, seeing as I don't have its length until the user inputs it? But once they input it, it needs to be stored somewhere, right?

Comment: @Ismael 1024 is usually a good bet with a static array - it would take a maniac to execed that limit for a file name.

Comment: @Ismael also yes row * col is the correct 3rd parameter to fwrite. What you need to do is loop over each element in the 2d array and within that loop, use another loop to go over each of the 1st pointers pointers. So you should have 2 for loops.

Comment: How/where is your 2D array declared? See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For a `type **` (*pointer to pointer to type*), you should write the total number of values as the first value in the file (and perhaps the size -- `char, short, int..` before that), then you will have to call `fwrite` once for each pointer to write the value. Depending on your declaration, there is no guarantee that the values are contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
 fwrite(fileName, sizeof(char), sizeof(boardState->board.theBoard), file);
```

means:

> Write data to the file `file`. The data is found at the memory location `fileName` points to, the data consists out of `sizeof(boardState->board.theBoard)` items and every single item is `sizeof(char)` bytes big.

Does that sound right to you? I don't think so; it's already wrong that the data can be found at the position `fileName` points to as you want to write the board data to the file and no the file name, right?

Also be careful with `sizeof()`; `sizeof()` cannot dynamically determine the content of some memory, it only knows the size of static memory. E.g.

```
char test[20];
size_t s = sizeof(test);
```

`s` will be 20. But now consider this:

```
char test[20];
char * ptr = test;
size_t s = sizeof(ptr);
```

Now `s` will be 4 or 8 as pointers are usually 4 bytes in size or 8 bytes in size. `sizeof()` gives you the size of the pointer here, not the size of the memory the pointer points to. There is no way in C to obtain the size of a memory block a pointer points to, this size must always be known.

You say your board is `char ** theBoard`, so theBoard is a pointer to an array of pointers to memory or characters.

```
theBoard -> [0] -> ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', ... ] 
            [1] -> ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', ... ] 
            [2] -> ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', ... ]
            :
```

In that case the creation code would need to look like that (assuming that [0], [1], ... are the rows):

```
 theBoard = calloc(numberOfRows, sizeof(char *));
 for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
     theBoard[i] = calloc(numberOfCols, sizeof(char));
 }
```

If that is the case, you need to write your data row by row:

```
for (size_t row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
    fwrite(boardState->board.theBoard[row], sizeof(char), numberOfCols, file);
}
```

Of course, assuming that all rows have have an equal number of cols.

If I can give you a tip, don't make the board `char **`, just make it `char *`, as it makes everything so much easier. See, if your board is 20x30 (20 rows, 30 cols), then you can define your board like this:

```
char * theBoard = calloc(numberOfRows * numberOfCols, sizeof(char))
```

Now you just have a single array, like this:

```
theBoard -> ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', ... ,
             'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', ... ,
             'a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', ... ,
             :
             ]
```

How would you access a specific field? Very simple:

```
 int row = 5;
 int col = 8;
 char field = theBoard[(row * numberOfCols) + col];
```

And then you can write the entire board in one call:

```
fwrite(theBoard, sizeof(char), numberOfRows * numberOfCols, file);
```

See, much easier. Also you can just free the entire board by calling `free(theBoard);` whereas when using the `char **` approach, you have to do this instead:

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
     free(theBoard[i]);
 }
 free(theBoard);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not just write the double-pointer to file. You have to index each element in the first pointer and write the data out in chunks of rows (or columns, but I've demonstrated rows).  To do this use a for loop. Note that (assuming the board is *all* you are saving to the *binary* file) the resulting file size should be `numRow * numCol` bytes.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < BoardState->board.numRow; ++i) {
         fwrite(BoardState->board.theBoard[i], sizeof(char), BoardState->board.numCol, file)
}
```

Reading ("loading") the file is done in reverse of the code above - note that it is unwise to only save the board to file - I suggest at the start of the file you save the number of rows and columns to make allocation of memory easy while reading (loading) the file.

So assuming you store the number of rows/columns in an int the above code then becomes

```
fwrite(&BoardState->board.numRow, sizeof(int), 1, file);
fwrite(&BoardState->board.numCol, sizeof(int), 1, file);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < BoardState->board.numRow; ++i) {
         fwrite(BoardState->board.theBoard, sizeof(char), BoardState->board.numCol, file)
}
```

*NOTE this has the possibility of introducing endianness problems. You can Google that if your interested.*

Comment: I will upvote your answer if you fix the calls to `fwrite()` for correct argument usage.

Comment: @Dúthomhas didn't catch that! Thanks - hard to answer/edit on mobile.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve learned it isn’t worth my effort unless I am seated in front of my PC.